# how to override System.Convert.Tostring Method in c#

Tags: c#, string

Need to override a System.Convert.ToString. i have achieved for string.Tostring() using stringextensions.is there a similar way to working for convert. please help to find a way to achieve this.

Comment: You can't override `Convert.ToString`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just implement [IConvertible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible) in your class. This is what is used by Convert internally (see [source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/convert.cs))

```
class MyClass : IConvertible
{
    string IConvertible.ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return "whatever";
    }
    // + all the other IConvertible methods
}
```